# How to load Image data from parquet file and labels from csv file to fastai

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, fast-ai

I am trying to use fastai library in https://www.kaggle.com/c/bengaliai-cv19 but can't find any documentation about loading image from parquet file.

I have converted parquet file to dataFrame and **ImageDataBunch** requires argument **path** but image is already in dataFrame how do I load it in ImageDataBunch.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the data frame and save the images into a folder and then use `from_folder` factory function of `ImageDataBunch` class.

From the description of the data from the kaggle website it appears that each row of the `parquet` file is a test image of shape `137 x 236`.

```
  image_id    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8  .....
0   Test_0  247  253  253  252  252  252  252  253  253  .....
1   Test_1  253  253  253  253  253  253  253  253  253  .....
2   Test_2  253  253  253  253  253  252  251  252  252  .....
.
.
.
.
```

I have tried this to get the first image.

```py
# get the image
>>> img = df.iloc[1,1:].to_numpy().astype(int).reshape(137,236)
>>> img.shape
(137, 236)

# Image_id
>>> df.iloc[1,0]
'Test_1'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is that means fastai API only works with image path not with image data, and can I save images on kaggle.